# Yocto Linux installation failed

Tags: yocto

I'm using "*CL-SOM-AM57x - TI AM5728 / AM5718 System-on-Module*".

I tried to install Yocto Linux which is provided by compulab: [Link](https://www.compulab.com/products/computer-on-modules/cl-som-am57x-ti-am5728-am5718-system-on-module/#devres).

I choose automatic installation but after installing, got some error and can't launch Yocto Linux on that device. ([Automatic Installation Instructions](https://mediawiki.compulab.com/w/index.php?title=CL-SOM-AM57x:_Yocto_Linux:_Automatic_Installation))

I posted the error below. How to install Yocto Linux properly? Why This error occurred?

---

```
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0

Saving Environment to SPI Flash...

SF: Detected w25q16cl with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 4 KiB, total 2 MiB, 
mapped at 5c000000

Erasing SPI flash...Writing to SPI flash...done

switch to partitions #0, OK

mmc1(part 0) is current device

** File not found kernel.img **
libfdt fdt_check_header(): FDT_ERR_BADMAGIC

No FDT memory address configured. Please configure

the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
Aborting!

No FDT memory address configured. Please configure

the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
Aborting!

No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
Aborting!

No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
Aborting!

No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
Aborting!

No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
Aborting!

No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
Aborting!

No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
Aborting!

No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
Aborting!

No FDT memory address configured. Please configure
the FDT address via "fdt addr <address>" command.
Aborting!

ERROR: Did not find a cmdline Flattened Device Tree
Could not find a valid device tree
```

Comment: Your u-boot environment is not set. You can use `uEnv.txt` if supported or `boot.scr`. You can find the boot command which is used for your target from `include/configs/<board.h>` in the name, `BOOTCMD` macro. You also set which device to boot from and location of Kernel, FDT.

Comment: Can you explain in detail because, i used to install it on automatic way which explained in the link that i posted above

Comment: You need to step through from https://pastebin.com/yHtC6B9i this file. You can start from `bootcmd` and run in reverse after interrupting the u-boot console

Answer (score 0):

In the bootloader(probably u-boot),you have to specify the boot environment.For loading the kernel and device tree,bootcmd must be set.To access board fron userspace a file system is required,which has to be mentioned in bootargs variable.

Answer (score 0):

too late, but maybe someone will find it useful:

your uboot environment is not set up correctly, so try to set up the default like is shown on the istruction you provided,troubleshooting section

1. stop autoboot hitting a key
2. setup default environment

env default -a

3. boot the device

boot